# Is the cardinality of the polynomial quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_n [x] /f(x)$ always finite?

Tags: quotient-spaces, polynomial-rings

For some polynomial $f(x)$ does the polynomial quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_n [x] / f(x)$ always have finite cardinality?

Also, I have noticed that the examples of polynomial (over $\mathbb{Z}_n$) quotient rings that I have seen so far, if $f(x)$ has degree $d$ then
$$
\mathbb{Z}_n [x] / f(x) = \left\{ [a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots + a_{d-1} x^{d-1}] \mid a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_n \right\}
$$
Is this always true?

Comment: This isn't necessarily true - take $n=4$ and $f(x)=2x$. Then each of $x^k$ are distinct in $\mathbb Z_4[x]/(f(x))$.

Comment: This is true if the leading coefficient of $f$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Bernard, what exactly do you mean by a 'unit'?

Comment: Unit in a ring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory).